# Borderlands 2: Uncle Teddy

Tags: borderlands-2

The mission `Uncle Teddy` appears to be broken, for me at least.

First, I picked up the mission. After dying twice, I pulled the plug on the fan, and entered the basement.

First thing I see?

[image]
*(The door is open, but in it's unopened state)*

Interesting..

I proceeded to open all of the loot doors, only finding 5 of 6 echo recordings. No doors, and no teal marker anywhere around any level where it is marked. No Diamond above any objects either. Echo6 is supposedly "In the Corner".

My game frequently glitches, and leaving the area and returning usually fixes it.

Usually.

[image]
*(The door is in it's unopened state, but stuck shut)*

A few other glitches occurred as well shortly before this, but I didn't think much of it. They included no skags spawning, breaking the sister mission `Hunger like the Skag`, and 3 of 5 echo recorders from `Get to Know Jack` failing to spawn. ((That's still in effect actually))

Where is the recorder, or where was it *supposed* to be? How do I fix, or if I can't, how do I "Band-aid" it? Is there something I did to cause this, or is Karma just catching up with me? Neither of these are story missions, so worst case scenario, I can simply ignore them. *Simply.*

**Bonus points:** How do you activate this lever?

[image]

Comment: I've never encountered glitches like this playing BL2 on Xbox. Are you playing on PC? The buttons make me think not, but maybe you're using a controller. The only mention of a glitch in this mission I can find is [Open ALL the containers to get every ECHO Recorder. But there is a glitch in which sometimes the last ECHO Recorder does not show up. If this happens, just leave and re-enter the game and search again](http://orcz.com/Borderlands_2:_Uncle_Teddy). Have you watched a video or something to determine exactly *which* one isn't showing up?

Comment: It's on Xbox One, the Handsome Collection.

I have determined which one it is, because of the story behind it. After you have found five Echo's, and listened to them all, none of them are the one she is looking for, so she states "He hid the last one in the corner somewhere. Why don't you check there?", and that's the end of it.

The marker on the MM points to it being in the locked locker, or just behind it on the bottom floor of the basement, however, the locker is, well, locked, and the corner behind is inaccessible. There is also no colored beam of light to indicate an item to pick up.

Comment: It sounds like you're basing that entirely on knowledge gleaned from your potentially glitched game. You should compare to an independent source. I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_AmHS6bUTc). The lever is pulled after getting all the echos. There is an ECHO or two in a vertical locker like the one in your screenshot. You should compare to the video and confirm that that's one of the lockers with an ECHO in it. If so, then it's just a problem with the door not opening correctly.

Comment: The lockers I got ECHO's out of were not the ones shown in the video, except for two.

The Sixth ECHO in the video was in a toolbox in front of a set of lockers-that toolbox provided me with SMG ammo. That locker is the only one refusing to open.

Thanks for the lever info, though.

Comment: Well if the location is randomized, then that's going to be difficult to know for sure, but if everything else opened, then it must be in the locker that won't open. I also noted that in that video, it looked like a wide-area marker, not a marker right on each ECHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That lever is used after finding all the ECHOs. It won't work because you're still missing one.

There are various videos of this mission floating around the internet. [Here's one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_AmHS6bUTc) from YouTube.

Based on the video and some discussion in comments, it appears that the exact locations of the ECHOs are randomized among the containers in the room. But, they're just in lockers and boxes, not any special scripted locations. So, if you've opened all the other lockers and boxes in the room but one that won't open properly, it seems clear that the sixth echo is in that locker.

This is a glitch, and it sounds like it's one you've already seen in your game. Since BL2 doesn't allow manual saves, the only things that you can do that might work would be leaving the area, which you say you've already tried, or quitting the game and reloading it. If neither of these work, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: I figured as much, I guess I just needed to hear the ugly truth. Sorry, but, thanks!